# What does "so" in "I am so out of here" mean?

Tags: word-usage

Ok,

The idiom "**out of here**" means *going or leaving* ([source](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/here_1?q=here))

So, *I am out of here*=*I am leaving* (not sure it means "*I am moving out right now*" or "*I will move out shortly*")

Now, we also have "*I am so out of here*".

My question is: does "**so**"="**extremely**" in this case?

So, "*I am so out of here*" = "*I am extremely out of here*".

But, seem noone says "*I am extremely out of here*", right?

Comment: It doesn't quite mean "extremely" but is used to emphasise the action being performed. The speaker isn't just "out of here" they are "SO out of here." It's used to somewhat hyperbolic effect as usually you can either be out of here or you can't; there's no degree to it so using "so" makes it feel more dramatic than it is.

Comment: Agree with John. It's emphasis of the form  "I'm out of here and don't bother trying to talk me out of it because the decision is made and I'm gone!" It may not mean it will happen any faster, but that it has now become an absolute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is an intensifier; it emphasizes the emotional state of the speaker.

The implication of "*so* out of here" (and you do have to emphasize it when spoken) is that it's long past time, or that whatever is driving you away is obviously egregious.

Often we use swear words for this in English ("I am f---ing OUT of here"; "I am bloody well out of here" in UK English might be a minced version of this).

It's also an in-culture marker, used by a particular generation/culture exemplified by, say, the movie "Legally Blond".

Note: "[getting] out of here" always means "leaving this place", but the place might be metaphorical, as in "I am quitting this job".

Comment: so, I am out of here = "I am moving out right now" (present continuous tense) or "I will move out shortly" (near future)?

Comment: also, "*so*" in "**he is not so good for you**" is the intensifier or it means "*very*" ("**he is not so good for you**"="**he is not very good for you**")

Answer (score 0):

“So” adjective to enhance a verb such as “out”. 1) Together a stronger emotional emphasis of the verb not to be reversed in consolidation or emotional reprieve. 2) used to state the intent to ensure clarity and remove confusion of the intent or otherwise misinterpretation of the recepiant. 3) Used for clarity of emphasis.